# Font used for video titles in Fire Stick's YouTube app

Tags: font-identification

After failing to get a definitive match with WhatTheFont and WhatFontIs (after almost 80 questions, no less) I'm here trying to identify the font in the title of this YouTube video, taken from what I believe is Amazon Fire Stick's YouTube app. The font feels to me pretty common so I find it odd that I've not been able to identify it so far.

Thanks in advance, it's much appreciated.

As a bonus, whether the font used for the descriptive text above the title is the same font or different would also be interested to know for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the good old **[Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) Black**, which is used in most Google products.

[image]